# Grouped multi output access query problem

Tags: sql, ms-access

A have a table that stores incoming case files and data for those case files, like case id, file id, date, file path and others.

I want to write a query that shows the case id and its file id for the latest entry.

I can create a query that show the grouped case id and max date, but I can't figure out how to show the file id for the last filed...file.

Here is the SQL for what I could do:

```
SELECT 
    iktat.caseid, 
    MAX(iktat.date) AS MaxOfdate 
FROM 
    iktat 
GROUP BY 
    iktat.caseid;
```

The data that I have

| Case ID | File ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID0001 | 1254 | 2022/01/02 |
| ID0001 | 0657 | 2024/02/02 |

What I want to achieve:

| Case ID | File ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID0001 | 0657 | 2024/02/02 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT iktat.caseid, iktat.fileid, iktat.date
FROM iktat
WHERE iktat.date = (
    SELECT Max(date)
    FROM iktat AS i
    WHERE i.caseid = iktat.caseid
);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/hSjB9nKt

Comment: I don't think this works in Access.  You can't join to an in-line view.  [Here is a support article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/sql-subqueries-microsoft-access-sql) on what subqueries are acceptable

Comment: Yes you are right I haven't read about MS Access. Updated my response. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, wroks perfectly and fast as well

Answer (score 1):

Your draft query will give you the latest `date` for each `caseid`  You could save it as a named query object (eg `qryLatestDatePerCase`) and then join that back to your `iktat` table like this ...

```
SELECT i.caseid, i.fileid, i.date
FROM
    iktat AS i
    INNER JOIN
    qryLatestDatePerCase AS q
    ON (i.date = q.MaxOfdate) AND (i.caseid = q.caseid);
```

Or, if you prefer not to create a named query, you can just join to its SQL ...

```
SELECT i.caseid, i.fileid, i.date
FROM
    iktat AS i
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT iktat.caseid, Max(iktat.date) AS MaxOfdate
        FROM iktat
        GROUP BY iktat.caseid
    ) AS q
    ON (i.date = q.MaxOfdate) AND (i.caseid = q.caseid);
```

Both versions work in Access.

Note [Date is a reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#D), so not a great choice for a field name.  If you can't rename it, make sure to qualify it with its table name (or alias) or enclose the field name in square brackets or backquotes wherever you use it in your SQL statements.

Comment: I tried the second one and it works perfectly. As for the field names, all of it has other names and in hungarian and so i changed the names to a simpler, english names so it can connect better to the question. Also first i accepted your answer , but tried Sohail Aslmas answer and gave the same results, but way faster, but still i thank you cause i learned something new today.